# #{cc.attrs} in nested custom composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component, composite-component

In JSF 2.2, I have a custom component `y:parent` including another custom component `y:child`, which has a component java bean and which allows children.

My problem is that `#{cc.attrs}` refers to the 'nearest' component, so if I make something like :

```
<!-- y:parent -->
<cc:implementation>
    <a id="#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}" />
    <y:child>
        <a id="#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}" />
    </y:child>
</cc:implementation>
```

The two `#{cc.attrs.myAttribute}` refers to the two components (first `y:parent`, then `y:child`), and not always `y:parent`, so the second access to parent attributes fails.

Is there a way to tell JSF to still refer to the parent component?

The only way I found is to use a `c:set` on the attribute I'm looking for, something like :

```
<!-- y:parent -->
<cc:implementation>
    <c:set var="myAttribute" value="#{cc.attrs.myAttribute}" />
    <y:child>
        <a id="#{myAttribute.myProperty}" />
    </y:child>
</cc:implementation>
```

Also, I discovered that EL evaluation are different for tag attribute and content, not sure why. I guess it depends on the JSF lifecycle. So, for example:

```
<!-- y:parent -->
<cc:implementation>
    <a id="#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}">#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}</a>
    <y:child>
        <a id="#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}">#{cc.attrs.myAttribute.myProperty}</a>
    </y:child>
</cc:implementation>
```

The two links will have the same content, but only the first `id` will be set.

Comment: Question is slightly ambiguous. 1) Try `#{cc.parent.attrs....}` in the second link element. 2) The `id` attribute being set at a different point in lifecycle happens only when it's set on a JSF component, not when it's printed as plain template text. In other words, the given code snippet doesn't at all demonstrate your problem with "EL evaluation are different for tag attribute and content". That would be only the case when you actually used e.g. `<h:link>`.

Comment: If I use `#{cc.parent.attrs}` for the second link (so inside the nested component), I got nothing : even `#{cc.parent}` doesn't print anything.    
And for 2), it's what I got, even with a `<a>` : the id (or any other attribute) is processed differently than the content.